# ReactJS: Search Bar Implementation

Tags: json, reactjs, apache-phoenix

I want to implement a search bar in my reactJS which takes query in the search bar and show the matching assets from the API with that query till it is finished and rendering it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface ApiResponse {
    data: Asset[];
}

interface FetchDataExampleState
{
    query: string;
    assets: Asset[];
}

  // The interface for our Language model.
interface Asset 
{
    city: string;
    country: string;
    lane_number: string;
    location_uuid: string;
    pin: string;
    id: BigInt;
}

class Search extends Component<{}, FetchDataExampleState> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            query: '',
            assets: []
        }
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.serachPeople(this.state.query);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ query: e.target.value }, () => {
            if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
                if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
                    this.serachPeople(this.state.query);
                }
            } else {
                this.serachPeople(this.state.query);
            }
        })
    }

    serachPeople(query) {
        const url = "/api/locations";

        if (query) {
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET'
            })
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<ApiResponse>)
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.data) 

// This is showing 0: {city: "bangalore", country: "india", id: 1, lane_number: "10", location_uuid: "1158", …}
//I have to search for location_uuid and show the row


        }


   }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="search-box"
                    placeholder="Search for..."
                    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                />
                {this.state.assets}
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default Search;
```

How to render all the matching location_uuids till the last one.
Then render the keys and values of the last one. I am new to ReactJS and tried other solutions. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: try console logging data.results and see if you're getting what you expect

Comment: It is giving undefined. Do you know the reason?

Comment: try console logging results.json as well?  Maybe your request isnt going through.  have you looked at your network tab in your browser?

Comment: Add `.catch(err => console.log(err))` after the last `.then()` you have around your `fetch()` to check if it's passing or holding an error.
I have brain-stormed my head of any cases that would pass the `!data.results` if it was `undefined` but, nothing popped-up except for maybe an error occured while fetching.

Comment: I changed a bit `.then(response => response.json() as Promise<ApiResponse>)
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.data)` now console is showing `1: {city: "london", country: "uk", id: 2, lane_number: "10", location_uuid: "1658", …}` Now how to filter that location_uuid and render it till the final search.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you have a look now.